# Arduino Nano не записывает данные на внешний EEPROM

Tags: память, arduino, микроконтроллеры, flash-память

Пытаюсь подключить EEPROM чип 24LC01B к Arduino Nano 328P, записать на него данные, считать и вывести в Serial Monitor.

Serial Monitor выводит только

Writing...
Reading...

Не могу понять в чём проблема.

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin(); // join i2c bus (address optional for master)
  Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop()
{
  Serial.println("Writing...");
  
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x50); // This is the 24LC01B device address
  Wire.write(0x0);               // Start writing at address 0
  Wire.write("Hell");            // Send 4 bytes
  Wire.endTransmission();       
  delay(100);                    // Without a short delay, the EEPROM is still
                                // writing when you start to write the next block
                                // Feel free to experiment with the delay length
  
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x50);
  Wire.write(0x4);               // Write next four bytes starting at address 4
  Wire.write("o Wo");
  Wire.endTransmission();     
  delay(100);
  

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x50);
  Wire.write(0x8);               // Write last four bytes starting at address 8
  Wire.write("rld!");
  Wire.endTransmission();     
  delay(100);

  Serial.println("Reading...");

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x50); // Now we're going to read it back
  Wire.write(0x0);               // Sending address 0, so it knows where we'll want
  Wire.endTransmission();       // to read from

  Wire.requestFrom(0x50,12);    // Start new transmission and keep reading for 12 bytes
  while(Wire.available())    
  { 
    char c = Wire.read();    // Read a byte and write it out to the Serial port
    Serial.print(c);         
  } 
  Serial.println();

  delay(5000);
}
```

[image: Обновленная схема]

Comment: Как минимум, не хватает pull-up резисторов на SDA и SCL

Answer (score 1):

Так ведь EEPROM_ADDRESS должен быть 0xA0 при записи и 0xA1 при чтении согласно даташита:
[image: Адресация EEPROM 24AA01/24LC01B]

Comment: 7-битный адрес `0x50`, о чём вы? Где ошибка? Библиотека `Wire` сама не умеет сделать `addr << 1 | Read_or_Write`?

Comment: Конечно не умеет. Она же не под вашу микросхему написана. Вы программист, и ваша задача - задать адрес.

Comment: Вы о чём? I2C — это стандартный протокол, в зависимости от метода `write()` или `read()` нормально написанная библиотека должна сама уметь это делать. Причём тут микросхемы?! С ваших слов, библиотека `Wire` написана "на коленке" скорее всего человеком, который не разбирается в том, как надо писать программы. :(